# Incorrect page labelling appendix

Tags: page-numbering, appendix

I would like to label my page numbers in the appendix as A1, A2 ... I used the following code, however, only my first page received the correct label A1, while the second page was labeled 2. Does anyone know why the labeling on page to is incorrect? Code below. Thank you!

```
\begin{appendices} \label{A}
    \newpage
    \renewcommand\thefigure{{A}\arabic{figure}}    %special numbering of figures
    \renewcommand\thetable{{A}\arabic{table}}    %special numbering of tables
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{{A}.\arabic{equation}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{A}
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
    \pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
    \renewcommand*{\thepage}{A\arabic{page}}
    
\section*{Appendix}
\normalsize

\subsection{Section 1} \label{sec:1}

\begin{table} [H]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}  
        \centering{
            \small
            \caption{caption}
            \label{tab:T_table}
            \input{Tables/T_table.tex} }
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\subsection{Section 2} \label{sec:2}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering{
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figures/F_xxx.pdf}
\caption*{\footnotesize \textit{Notes}: xxx.\\}
\caption{xxx}
\label{fig:F_xxx}}
\end{figure}
   
 \end{appendices}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really would have helped if you had provided an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document}`) instead of just a snippet. I had to waste time making your code processable.

Change the location of where you put the change to page numbers *before* the `appendices` environment.

```
% pagenumprob.tex  SE 576560

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{A section}

\newpage
    \pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
    \renewcommand{\thepage}{{A}\arabic{page}}
\begin{appendices} \label{A}
%    \newpage
    \renewcommand\thefigure{{A}\arabic{figure}}    %special numbering of figures
    \renewcommand\thetable{{A}\arabic{table}}    %special numbering of tables
    \renewcommand{\theequation}{{A}.\arabic{equation}}
    \renewcommand{\thesection}{A}
    \setcounter{figure}{0}
    \setcounter{table}{0}
    \setcounter{equation}{0}
%    \pagenumbering{arabic}% resets `page` counter to 1
%    \renewcommand{\thepage}{{A}\arabic{page}}

    
\section*{Appendix}
\normalsize

\subsection{Section 1} \label{sec:1}

\begin{table} [H]
    \begin{adjustwidth}{-1in}{-1in}  
        \centering{
            \small
            \caption{caption}
            \label{tab:T_table}
   %         \input{Tables/T_table.tex} }
      TABLE.TEX}
    \end{adjustwidth}
\end{table}

\clearpage

\subsection{Section 2} \label{sec:2}

%%    \renewcommand{\thepage}{{A}\arabic{page}}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering{
%\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figures/F_xxx.pdf}
 FXXX.PDF
\caption*{\footnotesize \textit{Notes}: xxx.\\}
\caption{xxx}
\label{fig:F_xxx}}
\end{figure}


   
 \end{appendices}

\end{document}
```